# Unity event missing link after add parameter to function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have function as below:

```
public void PlayIfNotPlaying()
```

but when i modified it into

```
public void PlayIfNotPlaying(float speed)
```

the `UnityEvent` will break.

[image]

Is there anyway to avoid this issue ? I heard about `[FormerlySerializedAs("myValue")]`, but it use for renaming serialized field.

Comment: This requires an Editor plugin and the code is a really long one. Three things to do: 1.Detect when the there is missing link in the UnityEvent. 2.Search to see if the function exists but with different param sig.  3.Map the new function to the Unity event.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788400/3785314) post is very similar and should get you started for #1 and #2. For #3, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655089/how-to-add-persistent-listener-to-button-onclick-event-in-unity-editor-script/41027533#41027533) post. By reading these two, you should be able to create a solution for this.