# Unity how to copy and paste UnityEvent in editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to copy and paste UnityEvent in editor without losing it references?

To copy events from "OnEnterScene" to "OnExitScene".

[image]

Comment: I believe I've made a comment to a similar question of yours with useful links  in the past. You need to find that comment in one of your posts and use the links there. It links to posts on how to get functions added to UnityEvents and how to subscribe to UnityEvent via code.

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691259/unity-event-missing-link-after-add-parameter-to-function#comment88392777_50691259), probably. Took me maybe thirty seconds, checking question titles and looking at the comments.

Comment: @Programmer Ya, I have a script to subscribe to UnityEvent via code base on that post. But how about if making the UnityEvent inspector clickable and show option to copy/paste. and I don't get the idea of storing the UnityEvent in some place for paste.

Comment: Well the title and body of this question is not "how to show option to copy/paste UnityEvent" but how to copy/paste event. At this moment I don't know what exactly you're shooting for but if what you want to do is what's in the question then the links should be helpful. Find the script in the event first, find the registered function and it's params. Now, create new event with that script and the function you retrieved.

Comment: Note that the best way to get people help is by posting your current code to show what you've tried. It will help people determine what you've one wrong

Comment: @Programmer yes I think the question is misleading, Let me reopen this question when its clear in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is an asset on the unity **asset store** named **Copy Paste UnityEvents**, after installing, you will see the nice copy-paste buttons below all of your serialized unity events in the inspector.

Link To Copy Paste UnityEvents
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/slug/214485